# SSRS Matrix with Blank

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am making a **matrix** of the TOP 10 users per month. I am using **ROW_NUMBER** in the SQL to identify the top 10.

[image]

Unfortunately, when there isn't 10 users for a given month, the first users repeats with a blank count.

How can I fix this?

The **row group** is grouping by my **ROW_NUMBER**. I am **column grouping** by month and year.
[image]

There is only 1 record for JULY but it is repeating on the other rows where I think it should be blank.

Comment: Try set the cell `HideDuplicates` property to DatasetName

Comment: @alejandrozuleta - I set the HideDuplicates property with the Dataset but that excludes them from future months also. If I use the ROW or COLUMN Group instead, it doesn't eliminate anything.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you need to add a group filter to your column group to filter for nulls. Expression=(Fields!HasDataID.Value=nothing)=false